# Misspecified parameter/dict when executemany with SQL

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

I am injecting data with `executemany` from a `pandas.DataFrame`, however I cannot use `pd.DataFrame.to_sql` for my case.

However, I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: parameters should be a list of sequences/dictionaries or an integer specifying the number of times to execute the statement

It does not look as if my list of tuples are the issue here, so what is causing this error?

My sample data:

```
 [('6385192776573', 'created - Balance - UK', 'fd7db8be', 'RED', 'LOOKALIKE', 8034000.0)
 ('6514685228569', 'created', 'fd7db8be', 'RED', 'PIXEL', 33000.0)
 ('6649478206141', 'created', 'fd7db8be', 'RED', 'MOBILE', 9000.0)]
```

My created table looks like:

```
'CREATE TABLE TEST ( Id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(256), AaccountId VARCHAR(256), AaccountName VARCHAR(256), Type VARCHAR(256), Users FLOAT)'
```

My script:

```
class sqlConnection:

    def __init__(
        self,Username:str, 
        Password:str, Host:str, 
        Service:str, Port = 1521, 
        Dialect = 'oracle', 
        SQL_Driver = 'cx_oracle'
    ) -> None:

        self._ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = Dialect + '+' + SQL_Driver + '://' + Username + ':' + Password +'@' + Host + ':' + str(Port) + '/?service_name=' + Service
        self._engine = create_engine(self._ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH)
        connection = self._engine.raw_connection()
        self._cursor = connection.cursor()

    def injectData(self, tableSchema: str) -> None:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        catList = dataColumns
        
        audience = df.apply(lambda x: tuple(x), axis=1)

        self._cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO {tableSchema}  ({catList})  VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6)", audience.values)
```

Whenever I run this I get the error as shown above.

Comment: Did you try `list(df.apply(...))`?